# Order elements by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items and two arrays:

- `favouriteItems`
- `blockedItems`

I want to reorder items by:

- only "favourites"
- not "favourites", not "blocked"
- only "blocked"

The problem with my script is that "blocked" items are above "not marked" ones.

What's wrong there?

```js
var favouriteItems = [2];
var blockedItems = [1, 3];

function isFavourite(id) {
  return (favouriteItems.includes(id));
}

function isBlocked(id) {
  return (blockedItems.includes(id));
}

function isNotMarked(id) {
  return ((!isFavourite(id) && (!isBlocked(id))));
}

$("div.container div.item").sort(function(a, b) {
  var aId = $(a).data("id");
  var bId = $(b).data("id");

  // check favourites
  if ((isFavourite(aId)) && (!isFavourite(bId)))
    return 1;

  if ((isFavourite(bId)) && (!isFavourite(aId)))
    return -1;

  if ((isFavourite(aId)) === (isFavourite(bId)))
    return 0;

  // check blocked
  if ((isBlocked(aId)) && (!isBlocked(bId)))
    return -1;

  if ((isBlocked(bId)) && (!isBlocked(aId)))
    return 1;

  if ((isBlocked(aId)) === (isBlocked(bId)))
    return 0;

  // both are not marked
  return 0;

}).appendTo("div.container");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id=1>Banana B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=2>Carrot F</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=3>Orange B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=4>Apple</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=5>Carrot</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the list of problems and improvements required in the code

- `check blocked` section and subsequent `return` was never executed because the function returned before that only as it covered all the 4 cases of equality between 2 variables.
- If the order is the same as required, then return `-1` and to swap return `1`. Hence, when `a` is **favorite** and `b` is not, return -1. Similarly, when `a` is **blocked** and `b` is not, return 1.
- When `a` and `b` are either both favorites or both not favorites, let the code check for being `a` and `b` are blocked or not and then finally return `0` (no change)
- There is an unused function `isNotMarked` which should be removed

You can simplify your sort logic as following.

```js
var favouriteItems = [2];
var blockedItems = [1, 3];

function isFavourite(id) {
  return (favouriteItems.includes(id));
}

function isBlocked(id) {
  return (blockedItems.includes(id));
}

$("div.container div.item").sort(function(a, b) {
  var aId = $(a).data("id");
  var bId = $(b).data("id");

  return isFavourite(bId) - isFavourite(aId) || isBlocked(aId) - isBlocked(bId);

}).appendTo("div.container");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id=1>Banana B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=2>Carrot F</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=3>Orange B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=4>Apple</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=5>Carrot</div>
</div>
```

Also, you can correct the logic in the same coding style as follows.

```js
var favouriteItems = [2];
var blockedItems = [1, 3];

function isFavourite(id) {
  return (favouriteItems.includes(id));
}

function isBlocked(id) {
  return (blockedItems.includes(id));
}

$("div.container div.item").sort(function(a, b) {
  var aId = $(a).data("id");
  var bId = $(b).data("id");

  // check favourites
  if ((isFavourite(aId)) && (!isFavourite(bId)))
    return -1;

  if ((isFavourite(bId)) && (!isFavourite(aId)))
    return 1;

  // check blocked
  if ((isBlocked(aId)) && (!isBlocked(bId)))
    return 1;

  if ((isBlocked(bId)) && (!isBlocked(aId)))
    return 0;


  // both are not marked
  return 0;

}).appendTo("div.container");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id=1>Banana B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=2>Carrot F</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=3>Orange B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=4>Apple</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=5>Carrot</div>
</div>
```

For reference, [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Comment: Great answer. Can you tell me what should I change in your code to make another order not marked > favourites > blocked?

Comment: @dafie - You will need to place another check just like favorites. Try it out else I will answer when I come back. Have to go somewhere

Comment: `return isNotMarked(bId) - isNotMarked(aId) || isFavourite(bId) - isFavourite(aId);` did the work :)

Comment: @dafie - Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are sorting your items the wrong way around!

The sorting function `f(a,b)` should return 1 if `b` comes before `a`.
In your solution the exact opposite happens

```
 if ((isFavourite(aId)) && (!isFavourite(bId)))
     return 1;
```

If `a` is a favourite and `b` is not, then `a` should come before `b`. Yet returning 1 indicates `b` becomes before `a`.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Answer (score 1):

The way your sort function is written, the code after "check block" will never be executed because the function will necessarily end at one of the three first returns.

If you write a single function for attributing value to the items that takes all the criteria in consideration, and then use it to sort them, It will work:

```js
var favouriteItems = [2];
var blockedItems = [1, 3];

function isFavourite(id) {
  return (favouriteItems.includes(id));
}

function isBlocked(id) {
  return (blockedItems.includes(id));
}

function isNotMarked(id) {
  return ((!isFavourite(id) && (!isBlocked(id))));
}

function sortValue(id) {
  var sortValue = 0;
  if (isFavourite(id)) sortValue += 2;
  if (isNotMarked(id)) sortValue += 1;
  
  return sortValue;
}

$("div.container div.item").sort(function(a, b) {
  var aId = $(a).data("id");
  var bId = $(b).data("id");
  
  return sortValue(bId) - sortValue(aId);
}).appendTo("div.container");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-id=1>Banana B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=2>Carrot F</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=3>Orange B</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=4>Apple</div>
  <div class="item" data-id=5>Carrot</div>
</div>
```